# Движением QLabel со скоростью значения из QSlider в рамках окна приложения

Tags: python, pyqt, qlabel, qtimer, qslider

В приложении есть два объекта:

1. горизонтальный слайдер,
2. квадратик, созданый через `QLabel` .

Идея программы: 
когда пользователь перетаскивает ползунок, то квадрат начинает перемещаться. 
Важно, что если встречает стенку, то меняет направление на противоположное. 
Чем больше значение ползунка, тем больше скорость квадратика.

Какая возникла проблема: 
Я смог сделать, чтобы значение слайдера передавалось программе, но не могу связать всё это с движением квадрата.

Было много попыток, но не одна не увенчалась успехом и я наконец-то додумался написать на форум, где люди шарят.

Ниже оставляю код, всем заранее спасибо.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import time
import threading


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(500, 500)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(174, 147, 255);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.horizontalSlider = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalSlider.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 420, 200, 50))
        self.horizontalSlider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.horizontalSlider.setObjectName("horizontalSlider")
        self.square = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.square.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 150, 60, 60))
        self.square.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 41, 144);")
        self.square.setText("")
        self.square.setObjectName("square")
        self.speed = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.speed.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 390, 100, 13))
        self.speed.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.speed.setText("")
        self.speed.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.speed.setObjectName("speed")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        
        self.horizontalSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.sl_val)
        self.sl_val()

    def sl_val(self):
        self.horizontalSlider.setMinimum(0)
        self.horizontalSlider.setMaximum(100)
        self.horizontalSlider.setTickInterval
        val = self.horizontalSlider.value()
        self.speed.setText("Скорость: " + str(val))

        def square_action():
            while self.horizontalSlider.value() > 0 and self.horizontalSlider.value() <= 100:
                if self.square.x() != 440:
                    time.sleep(1)
                    self.square.move((self.square.x() + val), 150)
                
        square_action()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Игрулька"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не изменяйте код, сгенерированный *Qt Designer*. 
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

То, что вы придумали, может выглядеть примерно так:

```
# ??? import time
# ??? import threading
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(500, 500)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(174, 147, 255);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        
        self.horizontalSlider = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalSlider.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 420, 200, 50))
        self.horizontalSlider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.horizontalSlider.setObjectName("horizontalSlider")
        
        self.square = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.square.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 150, 60, 60))
        self.square.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 41, 144);")
        self.square.setText("")
        self.square.setObjectName("square")
        
        self.speed = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.speed.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 390, 100, 13))
        self.speed.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.speed.setText("")
        self.speed.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.speed.setObjectName("speed")
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Игрулька"))


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):          
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setFixedSize(500, 500)
        
        self.horizontalSlider.setMinimum(0)
        self.horizontalSlider.setMaximum(100)
        self.horizontalSlider.setTickInterval
        
        self.val = self.horizontalSlider.value()                     # !!! +++
        self.speed.setText("Скорость: " + str(self.val))
        self.go_right = True                                         # !!! +++
        
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()                                 # !!! +++
        self.timer.setInterval(150)                    # Миллисекунды 
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updateTime)
        self.timer.start()        
        
        self.horizontalSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.sl_val)
        self.sl_val(self.val)
        
    def updateTime(self):   
        x = self.square.pos().x() 
        
        if self.go_right:
            x = x if x < 440 else 440
            if x < 440:
                x = x+self.val if x+self.val < 440 else 440
                self.square.move(x, 150)             
            else:
                self.val = -self.val
                self.go_right = False
        else:
            x = x if x > 0 else 0        
            if x > 0:
                x = x+self.val if x+self.val > 0 else 0
                self.square.move(x, 150)  
            else:
                self.val = -self.val
                self.go_right = True      

    def sl_val(self, value):
        if value >= 0 and value <= 100:
            if self.go_right:
                self.val = value
            else:   
                self.val = -value                
        self.speed.setText(f"Скорость: {value}")    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @ArtyomkaProgger что не так?